# operation on each row of dataframe1 against all rows in dataframe2

Tags: python, pandas

my code seems to do the job but I have hard time understanding the process.

I have two dataframe named nodes_df, rents_df.

rents_df:

```
        lng       lat   
0   137.014525  27.142947
1   117.130288  17.813582
2   116.926154  47.886767
3   137.014442  37.578488
4   154.063238  57.568705
```

nodes_df:

```
        lng       lat       Location
0   124.044525  43.542947    A
1   147.110288  65.513582    B
2   136.936154  31.556767    C
3   147.464442  33.508488    D
4   157.163238  12.508705    E
```

for location "A" I want to compare its distance each rows in rents_df and if create a column that includes number of rows in rents_df that is 100m within location "A"

I am using

```
def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(
        dlat / 2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon / 2.0)**2

    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    km = 6371 * c
    return km

nodes_df['count'] = nodes_df.apply(lambda row: sum(haversine_np(row.lng, row.lat, rents_df.lng, rents_df.lat)< 0.1), axis=1)
```

This seems to do the job but why?
from my understanding I am sending two coordinate points and two SERIES of coordinates into haversine function but I am confused if it actually compares each row with all rows in the series.

My result would be something like:

```
        lng       lat       Location   count
0   124.044525  43.542947    A          2
1   147.110288  65.513582    B          4
2   136.936154  31.556767    C          1
3   147.464442  33.508488    D          3
```

but want to make sure if I can trust count column.
    4   157.163238  12.508705    E